# HTML nomenclature

Tags: html

Are there terms for HTML tags that differentiate between ones which should have closing tags, and ones which shouldn't?

For example, `<em>` and `<a>` should have accompanying `</em>` and `</a>` tags.

On the other hand, `<br />` and `<img ... />` shouldn't.

What is the first group called, and what is the second?

Answer (score 7):

I *believe* that `<foo />` is an "empty element", as opposed to... not ;-p btw, `<br />` *isn't* an html element - it is an xhtml element. IIRC it is supposed to be `<br>` in true legacy html.

Comment: Oh snap, old-school HTML 1, Chris 0. :)

Comment: In fact, HTML doesn't have the <whatever /> style of tags at all. Some tags are always empty and thus don't need closing (like <img> and <br>), some tags can close automatically (like <li> and <p>) and other tags must always be explicitly closed. You can't do <div /> in HTML, only XHTML.

Comment: "Empty element" only describes lack of content.  Elements that cannot have content, like <br>, aren't empty.  They are whitespace.  Indeed, the W3C validator for HTML 4.01 gives a warning for <br />.

Comment: Hey, check that out!  The answer textbox requires you to escape your tags in order to see them, and the comment textbox does not.  So I hosed my comment above because I didn't know that.  Sorry!

Comment: Actually, the answer textbox uses markdown which prefers it if you use the `backtick notation` for inline code, and a 4-space indent for code blocks.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist:  The easiest way to escape HTML/XML content in an answer is by surrounding it with ` characters.  Then you don't have to do < (and so on).

Answer (score 5):

In XHTML the document has to be [well-formed](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.1). That includes that every element that has been opened with a start tag must have a corresponding end tag. Except it has no [content](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-content) (like other elements or text). Such elements are refered as [empty elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_2).

And the latter ones are empty elements as they don’t have any content.

Comment: I'd clarify this to say that they don't define any child content.

Comment: See the definition of empty (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-empty) and content (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-content) in the XML 1.0 specification.

Comment: I know how they define it, but just because w3 says it that doesn't mean it's any less ambiguous or confusing ;) - what they mean by "empty" is that it doesn't have any child elements, not that they don't have content.

Comment: So by your definition of empty this `<foo>bar</foo>` would be empty as it does not have any child elements.

Comment: No, "bar" is a text node. So perhaps I was too specific by saying "element" - but my point remains that "empty" means it doesn't have any children - I'd argue that an image specifies content in the src attribute. Also, I don't think the w3 spec actually has any language about not having content - all it says is "empty elements" and an example.

Comment: “Definition: The text between the start-tag and end-tag is called the element's content” (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-content); “Definition: An element with no content is said to be empty.” (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-empty)

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that in HTML 4.01 some tags (for example, [<p>](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1) and [<li>](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2)) can have content, but the closing tag is optional.

The following is valid markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Test
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to HTML 4.01, there are three different groups when it comes to elements and tags.

1. Elements that *must have* a closing tags.  E.g. <h1></h1>
2. Elements that *may have no* closing tag.  E.g. <li>
3. Elements that *may not have* a closing tag. E.g. <br> - the W3C validator for HTML 4.01 *warns* on <br />

I looked high and low in the specification and could find no term used to describe tags in the third grouping.

The term "empty" only says that there currently isn't any *content* between the tags.  This applies to 1 & 2 above.

My proposal: although W3C doesn't saying anything about it, as far as I could tell, it might be possible to refer to elements like <br> as "**white space elements**", since they are considered to be white space, and they are elements.  "White space characters", such as  , are not elements, so there should be no confusion.  Anyone see any problems with this?  If not, maybe we should make a proposal to W3C.